# Draw multiple elements to canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas

I successfully added an oval shape to the canvas, however now i'd like to add two more rectangles but for some reason they do not get added to the canvas. The oval shape is a ball which moves and rectangle shapes are static elements which are for "background". One rectangle should be as a floor and another one as an obstacle for the moving object, ball.

I tried to visualize it in the image:

[image: Result]

This is the code, mBack and mObs are the rectangles i'm trying to add.

```
AnimatedView animatedView = null;
ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
ShapeDrawable mBack = new ShapeDrawable();
ShapeDrawable mJump = new ShapeDrawable();
public static int x;
public static int y;
public class AnimatedView extends ImageView {

    static final int width = 50;
    static final int height = 50;

    public AnimatedView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        mBack = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        mObs = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xffffAC23);
        //mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
        mDrawable.setBounds(y, x, y + width, x + height);
        mBack.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
        mObs.setBounds(120,120,120,120);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        mDrawable.setBounds(y, x, y + width, x + height);
        mBack.draw(canvas);
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

mDrawable will be added however mBack or mObs not. Adding setBounds to onDraw won't change a thing also.

Comment: some context is missing in your code; x and y where are they defined? where are the drawables defined?

Comment: Sorry about that, now that's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are setting Bounds is wrong. The definition of the setBounds method is here:

```
setBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

for the two rectangles you are setting it as

```
mBack.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
mObs.setBounds(120,120,120,120);
```

This means you are left and right corners are same and top and bottom are same so you are not seeing your rectangle.

Set it something like this then you will see your rectangles

```
mBack.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 400);
```

And call draw method on both rectangle shapes in onDraw method.

Comment: Plus he is not calling draw() on mObs and he is setting bounds in onDraw().

Comment: Yes. He should call draw on both rectangle shapes. Updated my answer.

Comment: Oh i completely misunderstood the behaviour of setBounds (as i thought integer values there are for positioning not the endpoints). Thanks for your answer, will mark you as a correct!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that for mBack you defined the bounds to zero pixel (start end ends in (100,100)), same for mObs, but for that you didn't call draw either.